# Accessing the attribute of a child node through a variable

Tags: xslt

I am using XLS through C# and I need to be able to access the attributes of a specific node, but whatever I do I get the same "eof with @" error. Am I doing something wrong? Is there something I am missing? This is a code sample:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$main[1]@index"/>
```

Error message:

```
System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: 'Expected end of the expression, found '@'.
$main[1] -->@<-- index'
```

Comment: `$main[0]@index` is not a valid XPath expression. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: To step back a level, what you seem to be missing is a basic tutorial or reference book. You're not going to make progress with XPath by guessing the syntax and then asking on SO when your guess turns out to be wrong.

Comment: I have gone through W3School and stack overflow and I seem to be missing some key piece of information. @MichaelKay. The 0 is just an accident from other languages but it doesn't change the fact I can't even compile.

Comment: W3CSchools is handy for reference when you know what you're looking for, but it's not a good introduction to concepts, neither is StackOverflow. I'm old-fashioned: if I have to learn a new language, first thing I do is to buy a book.

Comment: Except I have 15 hours total to do this stuff and then never touch it again. I have gotten pretty good at picking up new languages on the fly and I have already done some relatively complicated stuff in xslt, but this is one bug I couldn't find anywhere online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an attribute named `index` of the context element use `@index`. Use that in a separate step if you first select elements e.g. `foo/@index` selects the `index` attributes of all `foo` children of the context node.

`$main[0]` doesn't make much sense as in XPath the first item has the index `1` so perhaps `$main[1]/@index` is what you want, it depends on how the variable or parameter `main` has been bound to a value.